# Referencing formula dates in a COUNTIFS statement

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

I have a set of dates on a sheet made of variations of the following formula:

Where `C1` is:
`=DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1),DAY(B1)+8)`

And `B1` is: `01/11/2013` in date format.

I'm trying to reference the cells in a `COUNTIFS` statement, to avoid having to type the date in each time, but it doesn't seem to register. The full statement looks like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!$BL:$BL, A7, Data!$BP:$BP, ">=C1",Data!$BP:$BP, "<D1")
```

Any idea what I'm getting wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this version suit?:

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!$BL:$BL,A7,Data!$BP:$BP,">="&C1,Data!$BP:$BP,"<"&D1)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much! I'll be looking super smug at work tomorrow :)